# redirect stdout from subprocess.check_call to function?

Tags: python, redirect, callback, stdout

Calling `subprocess.check_call()` allows to specify a file object for stdout, but before writing the data to a file, I would like to modify them on a line-by-line base.

I currently redirect the output to a temporary file (created by `tempfile.TemporaryFile()`. After `check_call` finished, I read that temporary file line-by-line, do the modifications and write the final output file.

Since the output is large, a pure in-memory-solution is not feasible and I would like to modify the data on-the-fly and write to the final output file directly.

Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

```
def check_call_modify(command, modifier_function, output_file)
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    for line in p.stdout:
        line = modifier_function(line)
        output_file.write(line)    
    p.wait()
    if p.returncode:
        raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(p.returncode, command)
    return p.returncode
```

to use it pass a function to modify each line, and the file. Dumb example below will save the result of `ls -l` in uppercase to `listupper.txt`:

```
with open('listupper.txt', 'w') as f:
    check_call_modify(['ls', '-l'], operator.methodcaller('upper'), f)
```

Answer (score -1):

Python is duck-typed, so you could always wrap your file object before passing it to `check_call`.

This answer has an example of [doing it for `write()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013843/how-to-wrap-file-object-read-and-write-operation-which-are-readonly/4013888#4013888) but, to be thorough, you'd probably also want to wrap `writelines()`.

Comment: -1: no, it won't work, since subprocess needs a object with a `.fileno()` method, and writes directly to the file descriptor returned by that. In fact, the file descriptor is passed directly to the subprocess, so python is not involved in the writing.

Comment: Odd. I thought I remembered being able to pass in file-like objects without a `.fileno()`. Oh well. My mistake, I guess.