# Using __getattr__ for implementing the decorator design pattern

Tags: python, design-patterns, decorator

Say you have `class Foo` which has 4 methods and `class FooDecorator`. From those 4 methods, `FooDecorator` only needs to decorate one method.

Is it ok from a pythonic/OO design point of view to use `__getattr__` for forwarding the requests to the decorated instance? This would basically remove a lot of boilerplate code in the deocrator class.

Example:

```
class Foo(object):

    def method_1(self):
        return some, stuff

    def method_2(self):
        return some, stuff

    def method_3(self):
        return some, stuff

    def method_4(self):
        return some, stuff

class FooClassicDecorator(object):
    def __init__(self, foo_instance):
        self._foo_instance = foo_instance

    def method_1(self):
        returned = self._foo_instance.method_1()
        return decorate_result(returned)

    def method_2(self):
        return self._foo_instance.method_2()

    def method_3(self):
        return self._foo_instance.method_3()

    def method_4(self):
        return self._foo_instance.method_4()

class FooGetattrDecorator(ojbect):
    def __init__(self, foo_instance):
        self._foo_instance = foo_instance

    def __getattr__(self, attr_name):
        return getattr(self._foo_instance, attr_name)

    def method_1(self):
        returned = self._foo_instance.method_1()
        return decorate_result(returned)
```

Which do you find more elegant? `FooClassicDecorator` or `FooGetattrDecorator` ?

Comment: I don't think I'd use either. I'd just subclass `Foo` and override the one method.

Comment: @Aya Yea... but the point of the decorator is that you should be able to decorate already existing instances. Taking the example from wikipedia you should be able to do Sprinkles(Milk(Whip(SimpleCoffe()))) or have a latte by doing Milk(Milk(SimpleCoffe())). The number of combinations or the order of applyting the decorators can be huge.

Comment: Why don't you just use a Python [decorator](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) then?

Comment: Pass. I can't really envision a concrete example of when I'd want to use this pattern in Python. Due to Python's dynamic nature, many design patterns for other languages end up becoming anti-patterns in Python.

Comment: @Aya I agree... But not for this particular case. The same use cases in which the pattern is useful in static languages would also be useful in dynamic languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this other question which is quite similar. The highest voted and accepted answer seems to be quite similar with my FooGetattrDecorator

[Implementing the decorator pattern in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118929/implementing-the-decorator-pattern-in-python)

Closing this and also marking as duplicate.