# Creating a class based on Pandas.DataFrame using the pandas.read_csv() function to initialize

Tags: python, pandas, class, oop, dataframe

My goal is to create an object that behaves the same as a Pandas DataFrame, but with a few extra methods of my own on top of it. As far as I understand, one approach would be to extend the class, which I first tried to do as follows:

```
class CustomDF(pd.DataFrame):
    def  __init__(self, filename):
        self = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

But I get errors when trying to view this object, saying: `'CustomDF' object has no attribute '_data'`.

My second iteration was to instead not inherit the object, but rather import it as a DataFrame into one of the object attributes, and have the methods work around it, like this:

```
class CustomDF():

    def  __init__(self, filename):
        self.df = pd.read_csv(filename)

    def custom_method_1(self,a,b,...):
        ...

    def custom_method_2(self,a,b,...):
        ...
```

This is fine, except that for all custom methods, I need to access the `self.df` attribute first to do anything on it, but I would prefer that my custom dataframe were just `self`.

Is there a way that this can be done? Or is this approach not ideal anyway?

Comment: In your first example. you probably just need to call `super().__init__(...)` in your overridden init so that the rest of the setup that occurs in `pd.DataFrame.__init__()` also happens in your custom class.

Comment: @Randy: I tried doing this, but still got strange results from the output. How would I want to implement the `pd.read_csv(filename)` portion of this code?

Comment: See the [Subclassing pandas Data Structures](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/extending.html#subclassing-pandas-data-structures) section of the docs; using inheritance is very much non-trivial.

Comment: @root: I was finally able to get what I was hoping for by doing `super(CustomDF, self).__init__(pd.read_csv(filename))`. Would this be an appropriate solution, or does this introduce any problems?

Answer (score 1):

The `__init__` method is overwritten in your first example.

Use `super` and then add your custom code

```
class CustomDF(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(CustomDF, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        # Your code here

    def custom_method_1(self,a,b,...):
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this though and didn't quite get what I expected. How would I put in my line where I want to assign `pd.read_csv(filename)` to `self`?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
class CustomDF:

    def  __init__(self):
        self.df = pd.read_csv(filename)

    def custom_method_1(self, *args, **kwargs):
        result_1 = do_custom_operations_on(self.df, *args, **kwargs)
        return result_1

    def custom_method_2(self, *args, **kwargs):
        result_2 = do_custom_operations_on(self.df, *args, **kwargs)
        return result_2

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go with the *decorator pattern* here. The accepted answer for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118929/implementing-the-decorator-pattern-in-python) will put you on the right track.

I see that your *first iteration* would be really cool, but it seem to me you need to know quite a lot of stuff about Pandas' internals, e.g., that this `_data` attribute need to be set in a certain way.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In my project I did something similar and use decorators, like manu suggested. The decorator `@property` might work for you, it basically turns the method `.df()` into a property `.df`. Therefore it will only be read in when it's called specifically. But this only works on instances of the class.

```
class CustomDF:
    
    @property
    def df(self):
        return pd.read_csv(filename)

    def custom_method_1(self, *args, **kwargs):
        result_1 = do_custom_operations_on(self.df, *args, **kwargs)
        return result_1

    def custom_method_2(self, *args, **kwargs):
        result_2 = do_custom_operations_on(self.df, *args, **kwargs)
        return result_2
```